# Calculate difference between two dates to calculate hours and minutes

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to get the difference in hours and minutes between two dates with the numbers after the colon in the number of minutes for a SharePoint List on SharePoint 2013.  For example:
1st Date: 1/5/2019 1:00 AM
2nd Date: 1/6/2019 2:15 AM
Total: 25:15

=INT((([Date Time Test]-Created)*1440)/60) this gives total of hours.  If I remove the 60, that gives total number of minutes or I have tried this: =INT((([Date Time Test]-Created)*24) which also gives the number of hours.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you will need three calculated columns:

1. one to calculate hours
2. one to calculate minutes
3. last one displays the hours & minutes

The big disadvantage of this approach is that all three columns will have to be included in the relevant views.

Second approach (depending on your SP version) - have a workflow calculate hours & minutes and output the result to a single line of text column.

Lastly you can also consider column formatting, depending on SP version again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `CONCATENATE` the hours and minutes, for example:

```
=CONCATENATE(INT((([SDate]-Created)*1440)/60),":",INT(([SDate]-Created)*1440))
```